# regex pattern using lookahead

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I am trying to find address line which would be followed by interface line like

```
interface
   ip address a.a.a.a
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to match multiple lines containing an ip address like format, one option is to make use of the [PyPi regex module](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) and the `\G` anchor.

To have a more precise pattern for an ip address, see https://www.regular-expressions.info/ip.html

```
(?:^interface Vlan\r?\n\s*description .*\r?\n|\G(?!\A))\s*(ip address \d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})
```

*In parts*

- `(?:` Non capture group for the alternation
- `^interface Vlan` Match literally from the start of the line

  - `\r?\n\s*description .*\r?\n` Match a newline, description and the rest of the ine
  - `|` Or
  - `\G(?!\A)` Assert the position at the previous match, not at the start
- `)` Close group
- `\s*` Match 0+ whitspace chars
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `ip address \d{1,3}` match `ip address`  and 1-3 digits
  - `(?:\.\d{1,3}){3}` Repeat 3 times matching a dot and 1-3 digits
- `)` Close group

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uv1eP2/1) | [Python demo](https://tio.run/##jZFBS8QwEIXv@RWzOSVLCXZ7EAQpHkQWVk/qKSixyWqgpmGSw8rqb6/jdpVi99AXBpLJIx@TFz/yWxeqvvfvscMM6F7djrFocnYY4BKQi/riyQc6bk3j4LE1QWOtg05L61KDPmbfBVDLQ/dT34h6oa@kpHvhIxhr0aUE2u7Lovqix7Q67uWeijOWXcrPKSPRBP8j6cAZjMSpxsDdoFO2EbZcnaszWuXEt5h0/g05hz@Tvprpq075QgfmpbEDENyPpsNwSaEhTSAOCaqtD9a0rTgGWcDvJxdDxOr2YXO/3qzvrqXs@28)

*Example code*

```
import regex

pattern = r"(?:^interface Vlan\r?\n\s*description .*\r?\n|\G(?!\A))\s*(ip address \d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})"

test_str = ("interface\n"
            "   description xxxxxxx\n"
            "   ip address 127.0.0.1\n"
            "!\n"
            "interface Vlan\n"
            "   description xxxxx\n"
            "   ip address 127.0.0.2\n"
            "   ip address 127.0.0.3\n"
            "   no abcd xxxxx eeeee\n"
            "!")

print(regex.findall(pattern, test_str, regex.MULTILINE))
```

*Output*

```
['ip address 127.0.0.2', 'ip address 127.0.0.3']
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

I come this far. But i can not detect the second occurrence in same Vlan.

```
(?<=Vlan)(?:.*?)(^\s*ip address \d.\d.\d.\d\s*$)(?=.*!)
```

I think you can you can work around this by capturing Vlan-! section first and searching ip addresses in this section.

You can see a working example here, i updated it: https://regex101.com/r/j7vtxZ/2

Comment: it should make sure that string `interface Vlan` should be ahead of it

Comment: Oh okey. Do you want to detect multiple or single addresses in a `interface Vlan`.

Answer (score 0):

If, as in the example, "interface Vlan" appears only once in the string you can use the following regular expression.

```
r'(?m)(?<=\bip address ).*(?![\s\S]+^interface Vlan$)'
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rtPydg/2/)<sub><sup><</sup>¯\_(ツ)_/¯<sup>></sup></sub>[Python demo](http://tpcg.io/qwBnYZUZ)

Python's regex engine performs the following operations.

```
(?m)                set mutliline flag
(?<=\bip address )  match 'ip address ' in a positive lookbehind
.*                  match 0+ characters 
(?!                 begin negative lookahead
  [\s\S]+           match 1+ characters, including newlines
  ^interface Vlan$  match line 'interface Vlan'
)                   end negative lookahead
```